# Continuously check page (client) height and change footer height according to that value

Tags: javascript, jquery

At my website, I try to accomplish (with javascript) that the footer height changes if the page height is larger then a specific value (907 pixels, the body height). It also needs to change if the page height changes (so if the viewer changes his client height).

I use jQuery to get the page height, but I need it's continuously checked, and not only when the page loads.

This is the snippet I use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var windowheight = $(window).height();
    if(windowheight >= "907") {
        var extrafooterheight = windowheight - 907;
        $('#footer').height(40 + extrafooterheight);
        $('body').height(907 + extrafooterheight);
    }
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest attaching to the resize event of the window using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var windowheight = $(window).height();

        if(windowheight >= "907") {
            var extrafooterheight = windowheight - 907;
            $('#footer').height(40 + extrafooterheight);
            $('body').height(907 + extrafooterheight);
        }
    });
});
```

Take a look at [the jQuery resize() docs](http://api.jquery.com/resize/).

Comment: Thanks, I knew it had to deal with how the function was opened, but I didn't knew how to solve it (I'm just a beginner to javascript and jQuery :)). But thanks!

Comment: No, I forgot to add a line with 'else', so the footer height didn't change back when it became smaller then 907px.. but that's just my stupid mistake... marked it again :).